# Disable textbox auto fill in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to know how we can disable auto fill text box values? It's not about disabling autocomplete by `autocomplete="false"`.

Comment: What do you mean by `auto fill`? Can you explain it, or show an image of it?

Comment: If you click save user name password save in browser it will be saved,When you open it again the values will get automatically loaded.

Comment: Did you try the various suggestions given in [Disabling Chrome Autofill](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)?

Answer (score 1):

```
mytexbox.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
```

or add attribute

```
autocomplete="off"
```